# Expanding the xamwebgrid row to show additional details

Tags: silverlight, xaml, infragistics

I have the following idea: when the user clicks on the more... button of a grid row, the row must expand into a detailed state that shows additional details for the current entry. I know that xamwebgrid provides an expand command, but isn't it just for hierarchical data purposes? How can I display some movie screenshots let's say, only in expanded view ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Silverlight DataGrid, you can use the RowDetailTemplate for this usage.
See this sample for an example: http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/ToggleRowDetail